# Is is possible to use a multitouch display on a desktop to control an iPhone or iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

Is it possible to take input from a multitouch display connected to a desktop computer and use that to drive an iPhone or iPad?  Basically, I would like the screen to act as a big iPhone / iPad, but have the input there run an actual device.

Alternatively, is it possible to mimic the iPhone or iPad using a multitouch monitor and the iPhone Simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to develop an Accessory Kit, and an app for a jailbroken iPad.

http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/

Like this one ?

http://www.engadget.com/2010/10/29/58-inch-table-connect-for-iphone-multitouch-surface-easily-dwarf